# How to automate aws sagemaker studio notebook

Tags: aws-lambda, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am quite new to AWS and trying to run AWS Sagemaker Studio Notebook when file is uploaded to S3.

I came to know that there is a difference between AWS Sagemaker Notebook Instance and AWS Sagemaker Studio Notebook.
Got approaches to run AWS Sagemaker Notebook Instance but not getting anything related to AWS Sagemaker Studio Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to schedule Notebook Jobs in Studio.

SageMaker Notebook Jobs gives you the tools to create and manage your noninteractive notebook jobs. You can create jobs, view the jobs you created, and pause, stop, or resume existing jobs. You can also modify notebook schedules.

When you create your scheduled notebook job, the scheduler tries to infer a selection of default options and automatically populates the form to help you get started quickly. If you are using Studio, at minimum you can submit an on-demand job without setting any options. You can also submit a (scheduled) notebook job definition supplying just the time-specific schedule information. However, you can customize other fields if your scheduled job requires specialized settings. If you are running a local Jupyter notebook, the scheduler extension provides a feature for you to specify your own defaults (for a subset of options) so you don't have to manually insert the same values every time. For details about how to schedule a notebook job, see Schedule a notebook job.

SageMaker Notebook Jobs dashboards help organize the job definitions that you schedule, and also keep track of the actual jobs that run from your job definitions. There are two important concepts to understand when scheduling notebook jobs: job definitions and job runs. Job definitions are schedules you set to run specific notebooks. For example, you can create a job definition that runs notebook XYZ.ipynb every Wednesday. This job definition launches the actual job runs which occur this coming Wednesday, next Wednesday, the Wednesday after that, and so on.

The interface provides two main tabs that help you track your existing job definitions and job runs:

Notebook Jobs tab: This tab displays a list of all your job runs from your on-demand jobs and job definitions. From this tab, you can directly access the details for a single job run. For example, you can view a single job run that occurred two Wednesdays ago.

Notebook Job Definitions tab: This tab displays a list of all your job definitions. From this tab, you can directly access the details for a single job definition. For example, you can view the schedule you created to run XYZ.ipynb every Wednesday.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/create-notebook-auto-run.html

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to run a SageMaker Studio notebook with no specific input or output parameters, there's a straightforward method available. You can utilize the SageMaker Studio toolbar located at the top of the notebook interface. Within this toolbar, you have the option to create a SageMaker job, and even schedule the execution of your notebook at defined intervals. This visual tool simplifies the process of managing and executing SageMaker Studio notebooks, providing a convenient way to automate their execution as needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).